# Clarification in CASE statement in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently came across a code where an assumption is made in the end of `case statement` in a join and I couldn't understand. Could anyone please tell me the purpose of using such method/code.

Code:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN #std b ON a.empid = b.mgrid
                                                   AND CASE
                                                          WHEN a.empname IS NOT NULL
                                                          THEN a.empname
                                                          ELSE a.mgrname
                                                       END = b.stdname
```

The bit I don't understand is `END = b.std`. I would like to know the purpose of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This second predicate of the `WHERE` clause is equivalent to:

```
COALESCE(a.empname, a.mgrname) = b.stdname
```

i.e. `a.empname` is used to compare to `b.stdname`, *unless* `a.empname` is null. In this latter case `a.mgrname` is used instead.

Answer (score 3):

`case` is an expression, it returns a value - in this case, either `a.empname` or `a.mgrname` (although in this case, it's silly - you should use `coalesce(a.empname, a.mgrname)` instead). The value returned is then compared to `b.stdname`.

That said, the join is a bit suspect anyway. You might want to think a bit about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same as:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN #std b ON a.empid = b.mgrid
                          AND (CASE
                                   WHEN a.empname IS NOT NULL
                                   THEN a.empname
                                   ELSE a.mgrname
                               END) = b.stdname
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see as `END = b.stdname` is not an expression in itself. The `END` is the terminating part of a [`CASE` expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

The `CASE` expression evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions. You can lookup the syntax in the link, you will see that it always ends in the word `END`.

The expression in the example you posted:

```
CASE 
  WHEN a.empname IS NOT NULL
  THEN a.empname 
  ELSE a.mgrname
END
```

returns one result based on the condition whether `a.empname IS NOT NULL`. If this condition is true it will return `a.empname` else it will return `a.mgrname`. This result is then compared to `b.stdname` as part of your `JOIN` conditions.